# Implementing a factory that can have different parameter combinations

Tags: c#, factory

I'm trying to implement a factory method that generates reports.

For this I created an interface named IReport, an ReportType enumeration detailing the different reports available and a ReportFactory class.

The idea is that depending on the type of report you could call the a GenerateReport method that would return an IReport object:

```
IReport GenerateReport(ReportType reportType);
```

However, different reports need different parameters.

- some reports only need a start date and a end date.
- a report that details a specific order needs an order ID
- another report needs a customer id and order ID
- and a few

The question:

Do I have to create a different GenerateReport method for each report type?

Is it a bad idea to create a class called ReportParameters that has all possible parameters and the factory method knows which parameters to use depending on the report type?

For example

```
class ReportParameters
{
ReportType RepType;
DateTime StartDate;
DateTime EndDate;
int CustomerID;
int OrderID;
}
```

And then use

```
IReport GenerateReport(ReportParameters params);
```

Any comments are greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> Is it a bad idea to create a class called ReportParameters that has
>   all possible parameters and the factory method knows which parameters
>   to use depending on the report type?

I don't particularly think so. That sounds like a type of factory to me. I have two thoughts further to this:

1. you could provide subclasses of this ReportParameters, for your different reports, and those subclasses could provide methods to help the factory determine how to create such a report
2. Factories aren't the only means to creating something. You could investigate [builders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) too

> The intent of the Builder design pattern is to separate the
>   construction of a complex object from its representation. By doing so,
>   the same construction process can create different representations.